# Variable indefinida PHP_SELF

Tags: php

Estoy realizando pequeño ejemplo para identificar cuando una página es recargada por segunda vez, uso php v5.7.14

PHP:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    echo "primera vez";
}
else
{
    echo "mas de primera";
}?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ReCaptcha Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form class="register" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="Nombre" required="required" />
    </form>

</body>
```

Arroja el siguiente ERROR:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

La variable está mal escrita debería ser algo asi:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

Comment: gracias amigo funciono con eso

Comment: me funciona sin el error ahora. pero necesito identificar cuando la pagina es recargada por segunda vez

Comment: No se que deseas hacer, pero me imagino que lo que buscas es evitar que se haga submit en el formulario dos veces, si es así puedes dar una leida a este patrón https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get, basícamente lo que dice que es que después de hacer post se haga un redireccionamiento.